# How do I fetch a component in React only if needed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, single-page-application

I have an SPA React application which currently loads all articles (each in the form of a react component) dynamically with require on a home page.

How can I not serve all articles at once but just the one that the user requests?

The problem is that I can't write the article in `json` or any other format except a react component (`.js` file) which I want to be served then from an `express` backend and rendered on the front-end. I know I can probably do server-side rendering but I don't want that as my server lacks the resources.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. do you want to load components only when used in route?
does https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy solve your problem?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the resources comment. Even storing your articles statically would consume less resources than transferring your entire library over the wire every time a client downloads the app?

Comment: @AnyDay, If I have 20 articles and the user is on the home page, why should I load all of them but not only the one user clicks on?

Comment: @RezaSam react lazy is something I will deeply research. It might solve my problem, thanks!

Comment: Unless I'm really wrong here, lazy loading isn't going to help you server side. Lazy loading is for conserving resources on the client. If you're packing every article in a component, when a user hits the app, every component gets downloaded. The only way to conserve data transfer is to store your articles server side and serve them as they are requested from a single component.

Comment: @AnyDay Seems like I'll need a huge project restructure..